# Can I play Minecraft Java for free after purchasing it on my Nintendo Switch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, macos, nintendo-switch

So I recently got Minecraft on my Nintendo Switch, and by the way, I logged in using my nintendo account and a microsoft account. Anyways, I just wanted to know whether I could play Mac version of Minecraft for free by logging in with the same Microsoft account on my Macbook and how, or is that not possible.

Comment: Well, you can play the demo version of Java Edition for free (regardless of any purchases), but it's very limited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/can-you-get-minecraft-java-for-free-if-you-have-purchased-minecraft-bedrock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Minecraft Java Edition and Minecraft Bedrock Edition (the Switch version) are separate games and you must buy them separately.